# How to center and enlarge text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, getelementbyid

I want to replace div content with a random text quotation (I am coding a Chrome web extension) which the code below does; but I don't know how to use javascript to manipulate the text so that I can center it, enlarge the text, bump the text down a few lines, etc. As I do not have access to the original HTML (this is for a Chrome Extension), I need to accomplish this with javascript. Is this possible?

```
const quotes = [
'Quotation 0.',
'Quotation 1.',
'Quotation 2.'
];
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
document.getElementById('pageContent').outerHTML = quotes[index];
```

Answer (score 1):

js does not cause the rendering of text, the browser interprets the html and css to render the text. You can use js to inject html and css for you desired effect. If you can not directly edit the html or css document, you can use inline stylings to create visual effects, however chrome extension do have the ability to inject css as well as js.

How about something like modification to the code you provided:

```js
const quotes = [
  'Quotation 0.',
  'Quotation 1.',
  'Quotation 2.'
];
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
const h2 = document.createElement("h2");
h2.style.cssText = `
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 1rem;
`;
h2.innerText = quotes[index];

document.getElementById('pageContent').appendChild(h2);
```

Comment: I am getting an "Invalid or Unexpected Token" error from Chrom (in the developer mode for testing an extension) for line of code that starts with h2.style.cssText

Comment: @Jago, just tested again on my end, no errors. What method are you using to inject the script? If you have a github repo I don't mind making a pull request

Comment: This fixed it (looks like I just needed to use double quotes instead of single quotes):
h2.style.cssText = "text-align: center;font-size: 3rem;margin: 1rem;";

Comment: Also, as I wanted to get rid of pageContent, I looked up the appendChild and discovered  replaceWith() and that worked perfect for your code! Thank you!

Comment: Ah I see, the issue was you did not use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which would allow multi-line string like syntax. They are `\`` backticks not quotation marks or apostrophes 

Comment: You are talking Klingon to me lol! My book on javascript just arrived today so I am going to get busy studying it.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) question.

You can use CSS's

```
text-align: "center"
font-size: "130%"
```

I also advise you to look into what other settings font-size can have (vis-a-vis percentage). It is better if you can apply these styles on a CSS stylesheet. But if you want to do it in JavaScript, you can do

```
myElement.style.textAlign = "center";
myElement.style.fontSize = "130%"
```